# Incorrect Counting on Binary Recursion function

Tags: c++, recursion, counter, computer-science, binary-search

So the idea of this code is that I have a binary search function that uses recursion, and the added feature I have is that it counts the amount of recursions that have happened and it also counts the amount of comparisons it made and outputs it. However, with this project, I have ran into the problem of my code outputting the wrong amount of recursions and comparisons.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

// Global variables to count calls and comparisons
int recursions = 0;
int comparisons = 0;

// Read integers from input and store them in a vector.
// Return the vector.
vector<int> ReadIntegers() {
   int size;
   cin >> size;
   vector<int> integers(size);
   for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {               // Read the numbers
      cin >> integers.at(i);
   }
   sort(integers.begin(), integers.end());
   return integers;
}

   int BinarySearch(int target, vector<int> integers, int lower, int upper) {
    if(lower<=upper){
        int mid = lower +(upper - lower) / 2;

        comparisons++;

        if(integers.at(mid) == target){
            return mid;
        }
        else if (integers.at(mid) < target){
            recursions++;
            return BinarySearch(target, integers, mid +1, upper);
        }
        else if (integers.at(mid) > target){
            recursions++;
            return BinarySearch(target, integers, lower, mid -1);
        }
    }

    return -1;

}

int main() {
   int target;
   int index;

   vector<int> integers = ReadIntegers();

   cin >> target;

   index = BinarySearch(target, integers, 0, integers.size() - 1);
   printf("index: %d, recursions: %d, comparisons: %d\n",
          index, recursions, comparisons);

   return 0;
}
```

So the input I put in is:

```
9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2
```

And the output should be:
`index: 1, recursions: 2, comparisons: 3`

The crazy wacky thing is I keep getting the incorrect amount of recursions and comparisons because my program outputs this:
`index: 1, recursions: 1, comparisons: 2`

It feels like im always one short or one too high. The function finds the index with no problems.

Maybe this is something of a logical mistake on my part, but I truly do believe I did everything right. I am just missing something.

If anyone can help me break down what I have did wrong, I would greatly appreciate that! Thank you so much in advanced.

Comment: How do you know what the output should be versus what it is? Does the first call of the function count as a recursion? Does each comparison for `=`, `<`, `>` count as a comparison?

Comment: The tool of choice for this will be the debugger. You have a list of expectations, so you should be able to step through the code and spot where those expectation start being violated. That'll be a bug. Might not be the only one, though. Anyway, once you see the aftermath of the bug, inspect what you can to gather information and then step through again (but since you know where the problem is you can probably accelerate things with breakpoints) and see what happened leading up to the bug in case you missed something the first time and to gather more information.

Comment: If you're still stuck, add the observations you've made while debugging to improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code is actually correct. Try putting a print statement inside `BinarySearch()` to print the value of `mid` each time it is calculated. I think you will find that the first index checked is 4, then a recursion where the next index is 1, which is your target.